# jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.8.0 stops working when updating to higher version

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

this docker-compose with a webserver and jwilder/nginx worked perfectly on 0.8.0 but when updating to higher version it stops working (502 bad gateway).

Any ideas what i missed?

this works, but when updating jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.8.0 to higher version like 1.4.0 it stops working. What changes were introduced, how to fix it?

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy

services:

  nginx-test:
    image: rocker/shiny-verse:4.2.1
    container_name: test
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    environment: 
      - "VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy"
      - "VIRTUAL_PORT=80"
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=http.mydomain.ch"
    restart: always

  nginx: 
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.8.0
    container_name: mynginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
   - ../geoCertbot/certs/live/mydomain.ch/fullchain.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/mydomain.ch.crt:ro
      - ../geoCertbot/certs/live/mydomain.ch/privkey.pem:/etc/nginx/certs/mydomain.ch.key:ro
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.servertype == web]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems from higher versions one must add "expose -80"